# Not allowed to access Renderer.material on prefab object. Use Renderer.sharedMaterial instead

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Long story short. I'm instantiating 4 types of coloured spheres. The player chooses his color, then he can take the spheres that are the color he has chosen. The player can only take one, then has to do another thing.

I'm not being able to check the sphere's colors. Since they are prefabs i cant use

esferas.GetComponent().material.color == Color.yellow

and Renderer.sharedMaterial doesn't work....

Comment: One approach here is to write a script with a color field and attach it to the gameobject. Then assign the same color to the field when you set the material's color. Or, better yet have it be an `enum` so you can have type guarantees.

Comment: Its actually one sphere but it changes   to 1 of the 4 different colors.

Comment: Right, so when you `GameObject newSphere = Instantiate(prefab);` you could do `newSphere.GetComponent<MyScript>().color = MyScript.MyColorEnum.black;` and then in the player `MyScript.MyColorEnum playerColor;`  then when you pick the player's color `playerColor = MyColorEnum.whatever;`. Then when you collide with a sphere: `if (playerColor != collidedSphereGameObject.GetComponent<MyScript>().color) { ... }`

Comment: You haven't shared the code you're using to instantiate the spheres and set their color so it's unclear what to write in an answer

Comment: I know i haven't gave much information here but thanks man.